# Comparing lists and elements

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to compare and retrieve values from corresponding lists. My Predicate is `correspond_elements(V1, Xs, V2, Ys)`, where I expect the following behavior:

```
?- correspond_elements(a, [a,b,b,a], X, [1,2,3,4]).
X = 1;
X = 4.
```

Where `V1` is checked in the first list `Xs`, and the corresponding values in `Ys` are given to `V2` to return. So far I have this:

```
% checks if the argument is a list
is_list([]).
is_list([_|T]) :-
    is_list(T).

% predicate
correspond_elements(V1, [X|Xs], V2, [Y|Ys]) :-
    is_list([X|Xs]),
    is_list([Y|Ys]),
    ( V1 == X ->
        V2 is Y
    ;
        correspond_elements(V1, Xs, V2, Ys)
    ).
```

Which only gets the first value:

```
?- correspond_elements(a, [a,b,b,a], X, [1,2,3,4]).
X = 1.
```

I know that once the `->` clause becomes true, then anything after the `;` is not executed. It is clear that my code will only get the first answer it finds for `X` and stop, but I am unsure of how to keep recursing through the list and return all the possible answers for `X`, even after the first answer has been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out yourself, the if-then-else of Prolog `A -> B; C` will check the condition `A`, and if `true` it will execute `B` (and not `C`). Otherwise it will execute `C` (and not `B`).

You however want to execute `C` as an additional option in case `A` is `true`. This can be done, by transforming:

```
foo(Some,Parameters) :-
    A
    -> B
    ; C.
```

into:

```
foo(Some,Parameters) :-
    A,
    B.
foo(Some,Parameters) :-
    C.
```

Since now `A` works as a guard for `B`, but regardless whether `A` succeeds or fails, Prolog will backtrack and execute the second `foo/2` clause.

If we remove the `is_list(..)` predicates (which are a bit verbose in my opinion), we can produce the predicate:

```
correspond_elements(X, [X|_], Y, [Y|_]).
correspond_elements(V1, [_|Xs], V2, [_|Ys]) :-
    correspond_elements(V1, Xs, V2, Ys).
```

We do not have to write the condition `V1 == X` here, since we used unification in the head for this. Because we use unification, it is `V1 = X` (one equation sign), so that means we can use the predicate in a more multi-directional way.

Querying the elements in the second list `X`:

```
?- correspond_elements(a, [a,b,b,a], X, [1,2,3,4]).
X = 1 ;
X = 4 ;
false.
```

Querying all tuples `A` and `X` of both lists (some sort of "zip"):

```
?- correspond_elements(A, [a,b,b,a], X, [1,2,3,4]).
A = a,
X = 1 ;
A = b,
X = 2 ;
A = b,
X = 3 ;
A = a,
X = 4 ;
false.
```

Obtain the elements in the first list:

```
?- correspond_elements(A, [a,b,b,a], 1, [1,2,3,4]).
A = a ;
false.
```

Generate a list such that `1` is in the list:

```
?- correspond_elements(A, [a,b,b,a], 1, L).
A = a,
L = [1|_G1285] ;
A = b,
L = [_G1284, 1|_G1288] ;
A = b,
L = [_G1284, _G1287, 1|_G1291] ;
A = a,
L = [_G1284, _G1287, _G1290, 1|_G1294] .
```